# New Google Charts Error when clicking on row in table. Uncaught TypeError: b.split is not a function -- Has been working for several years

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

We have multiple Google Visualization tables that we have been successfully using for several years.  However, in the past week, we started seeing this error in many of them

[image: Uncaught TypeError: b.split is not a function]

What we are trying to do is click on a row in a table to allow us to hyperlink to another page based on the contents in that row.  As I said, it has been working for several years.  I know exactly where it breaks. It is this line that triggers the error:

```
var row = table.getSelection()[0].row;
```

I know it is this row because the hyperlink works as expected if I hardcode a value for ROW.

Any suggestions for what might be causing this error on code that hasn't changed?

Here's the code:

```
        <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

    google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages:["table"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

    function drawVisualization() {

                    var d = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([$tableReportResults]);

                    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_report_results'));

                    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(d);
                            
                    var cssClassNames = {'hoverTableRow': 'hover-table-row', headerCell: 'googleHeaderCell'};
                    var colIndex = 0;
                    var  last_row = d.getNumberOfRows() -1;
                    var ts =  $( "#dropdown_1_dropdown option:selected" ).val();

                    var syear =  $( "#dropdown_2_dropdown option:selected" ).text();
                    syear = encodeURIComponent(syear);
                    google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', function () {
                        $('.google-visualization-table-table').find('td').each(function() {
                            $(this).mouseover(function(){
                                    colIndex = $(this).index();
                                    var row = $(this).parent().index() - 1; // subtract 1 for the table header
                                    //console.log(row, colIndex);
                             });
                        });
                    });

                        google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'select', function() {           

                            $('.google-visualization-table-table').find('td').each(function() {
                                $(this).mouseover(function(){
                                        colIndex = $(this).index();
                                        row = $(this).parent().index() - 1; // subtract 1 for the table header
                                        console.log('mouseover = ' + colIndex + ' , ' + row);
                                        }); 
                                });
                                
                        var row = table.getSelection()[0].row;
```

Comment: for starters, you're using an old version of google charts, try updating to the latest version, see [update library loader code](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#update-library-loader-code)...

Comment: Thanks, @WhiteHat.  I have updated the google charts version.  However, I'm still seeing the same error.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Although your code was losing the old version, we implemented a redirect to the new version. Loading 1.1 uses the upcoming version, which is different from the current version during each new release cycle. We just finished the release of version 50.

Comment: the `'select'` event is fired when a row is selected AND unselected. when unselected, `getSelection` will be empty (`getSelection()[0]` will return nothing). make sure the length of `getSelection` is greater than zero before trying to access selection elements.

Comment: @WhiteHat, it is definitely the getSelection line of code that is causing the error.  

'       var row = 0;
       //row = table.getSelection()[0].row;
'
If I comment out the getSelection code and hard code a value for row (like above), the table works as expected.  

Since this has worked for several years, I'm leaning towards the answer below from Marco.  However, I'm trying to be sure.

Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved my issue using the prior version 49 of google charts.

```
 <script>
      google.charts.load('49', 
        {packages: ['corechart']});
    </script>
```

or:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    {literal}google.charts.load('49', {packages: ['corechart', 'geochart', 'timeline', 'gantt', 'treemap']});{/literal}
</script>
```

If you use the actual version yo should change your code as per the following information:

https://groups.google.com/g/google-visualization-api/c/G4Keck3KVwU

Comment: Thanks, that got me out of trouble until I can do some more investigation.

Comment: Thanks @marco-cahuas. That worked for me too.  I'm still not sure what causes the issue with version 50, but I am chatting with Daniel LaLiberte on the google-visualizations-api group in Google Groups.